# Reset Dell IDRAC 8

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, drac, dell-openmanage

I recently imported a wrong SSL Certificate onto our IDRAC, now I get the following message on any computer when trying to log onto the console.

How can I delete out the custom SSL certificate or reset the IDRAC? I tried system setup F2 on boot, but there wasn't any option to reset the IDRAC.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the SSL certificate as explained [in this page](https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr/fr/frbsdt1/sln310599/idrac-web-server-certificate-management?lang=en).

Otherwise you can [reset the idrac](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjY4KKZufHcAhUqyYUKHbPNC9cQFjABegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dell.com%2Fsupport%2Farticle%2Fus%2Fen%2F04%2Fsln305793%2Fhow-to-reset-the-internal-dell-remote-access-controller-idrac-on-a-poweredge-server-&usg=AOvVaw3Twx9iE-84BY2DpC8LR0gb) to factory settings

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.